# Valores diferentes entre variável sem valor e variável com valor nulo?

Tags: c, int

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main ( void ){
int die1[7];
int die2[7];
int sortedDie, i;


srand(time(NULL));
printf("Rolling die 1\n");

for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){


    die1[i] = 1 + rand()%6;



}
printf("Rolling die 2\n");

for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    int dieValue2;
    dieValue2 = 1 + rand()%2;
    die2[i] = dieValue2;

}


printf("The numbers sorted in die 1 are: \n");
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    printf("%d\n", die1[i]);
}
printf("The numbers sorted in die 2 are: \n");
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    printf("%d\n", die2[i]);

}
printf("The sum of those numbers are: \n");
int sum = 0;  /* essa parte aqui */
for( i = 0; i < 6; i++){


    sum = sum + die1[i] + die2[i];

}
printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Pessoal, quando rodo esse programa com a variável `sum` apenas declarada como `int` sem ter valor atribuído a ela, ou seja: `int sum;` o programa me retorna uma soma que tem valores a mais. Porém, quando atribuo um valor nulo à `sum` tal como foi feito na parte comentada do código, ele me retorna a soma certa. Por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O nome disso é inicialização. Assim você inicializa a variável:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Ou seja, a inicialização ocorre quando você declara uma variável já lhe atribuindo um valor inicial.

Já dessa outra forma, você a declara sem inicializar:

```
int sum;
```

No seu `for`, você tem isso:

```
    sum = sum + die1[i] + die2[i];
```

Ou seja, modifica o valor de `sum` com base no valor anterior. Mas, na primeira iteração desse `for`, se você declarou `sum` sem inicializar, qual seria o primeiro valor dela?

A resposta é que o valor inicial dela é **qualquer coisa**. Frequentemente essa "qualquer coisa" é zero, mas pode não ser. Frequentemente esse valor é chamado pelo carinhoso nome de "**lixo**".

Ok, mas talvez você esteja pensando, por que o C tem esse comportamento tão bizarro? A resposta está na forma como a memória é organizada.

No C, cada variável é alocada em algum lugar da memória. Quando um programa está rodando, uma determinada parte dele pode utilizar alguma porção da memória para fazer alguma coisa qualquer e assim que termina, libera essa porção de memória. **Ocorre que liberar não é limpar.** Os valores antigos da função/procedimento/alguma-outra-coisa que terminou ficam largados lá na memória. Depois de algum tempo, uma outra parte do programa aloca aquela região de memória (que está suja) novamente e começa a utilizá-la.

Ou seja, o que acontece é que o conteúdo original da variável `sum` está sujo, e contém uma informação que é resto de alguma outra parte de alguma outra coisa que estava utilizando esse pedaço de memória para alguma outra finalidade.

E então, vem a pergunta: Por que ele não é limpo quando a variável `sum` é alocada? A resposta é porque isso quase sempre é desnecessário. É para isso que serve a inicialização. A inicialização não é só para definir qual é o valor inicial da variável, mas também é para apagar/sobreescrever qualquer lixo que lá esteja. E daí você pergunta, e por que ele não é limpo assim mesmo? A resposta é porque isso significaria que ele poderia acabar sendo limpo duas vezes, uma automaticamente e uma pela inicialização ou pela primeira atribuição de um valor a variável, o que significa que se o compilador gerasse código para limpar a variável automaticamente antes de usar, o resultado seria um desperdício de desempenho.

E por que que quem a utilizou por último, não a deixou limpa? A resposta é porque esse código, seja o que for, não mandou limpar! E limpar deveria ser desnecessário, vez que quem for utilizar essa parte da memória depois provavelmente iria/deveria sobreescrever o seu conteúdo com alguma outra coisa.

Concluindo, utilizar valores sujos da memória é uma péssima prática de programação, é considerado um bug. Na prática, não dá para se saber com certeza qual é o valor antigo, e seja ele o que for, provavelmente não seria qualquer valor útil. Esse valor é lixo, sujeira, alguma coisa qualquer sobre o qual nada sabemos e que não podemos controlar e que portanto é algo inútil. **Nunca utilize valores sujos da memória.**

Por fim, várias ferramentas de análise de código gerarão alertas avisando que a variável `sum` pode não estar sendo inicializada adequadamente - Talvez o próprio compilador esteja te dando uma advertência/aviso (*warning*) acerca desse problema.